# Django, display image in template that is uploaded from admin panel

Tags: python, django, image, django-views

i'm learning to upload and display images in Django but I've run into a block where I can't figure out how to call the images location from the database and then display it in a template, i've uploaded image from admin panel and wants to display it in template...

**models.py**
from django.db import models
from time import time

```
class Couple(models.Model):
    image_bride = models.ImageField(upload_to='vivaah/static/media')
    image_groom = models.ImageField(upload_to='vivaah/static/media')
```

**vivaah/views.py**

```
def index(request, bride_first_name, groom_first_name):
    obj = Couple.objects.get(bride_first_name__iexact=bride_first_name)
    image_bride = obj.image_bride
    image_groom = obj.image_groom
    context = {'image_bride':image_bride, 'image_groom':image_groom}
    return render(request, 'vivah/index.html', context)
```

**templates/index.html**

```
<img class="profile_pic" src="{{ image_bride.url }}"/>
```

**vivaah/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from . import views
import os

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<bride_first_name>[a-zA-Z]+)weds(?P<groom_first_name>[a-zA-Z]+)/$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin


from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
import os


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^vivah/', include('vivaah.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/media/')**

it shows only borders of the image but not actual image
[image]

Comment: Please add the html output of that image tag..

Comment: @ShrinathShenoy i've uploaded screenshot of html output :)

Comment: I meant to say copy the source of the HTML page that renders in your browser. You can grab it by rightclick clicking on any part of the page and selecting "view page source" option in chrome/firefox. Copy the output of this part of the source <img class="profile_pic" src="{{ image_bride.url }}"/> that renders.

Comment: Can you confirm that a URL is output in your `src` attribute on your `img` element? If that's the case, can you confirm that you can visit the URL and see the image?

Answer (score 1):

In your **templates/index.html**, you asking for url on *couple* object 
`<img class="profile_pic" src="{{ couple.image_bride.url }}"/>` but *couple* is not passed to your template.

Change this line `context = {'image_bride':image_bride, 'image_groom':image_groom}`
to this `context = {'couple': obj}`

Comment: i've already passed {'image_bride':image_bride} which is [image_bride = obj.image_bride] @tsh